# In SQL: How to obtain percentage of two columns grouped by month

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the percentage of the monthly sums of two columns in SQL.

Lets say these were July's individual entries

```
Column A | Column B
4 | 10
2 | 8
0 | 0
7 | 12
```

I want: 13/30 = 0.43

This is what my query looks like

```
Select sum(Column 1)/sum(Column 2) as 'Current Success %'
from Table
where Month Code between 110 and 124
group by Month Code
```

When I run this, all columns read '0'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that your version of SQL does integer division.  Try this:

```
select sum(Column 1) * 1.0 /sum(Column 2) as success_ratio
```

I strongly recommend that you use single quotes only for string and date constants, and not for the names of columns.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Wait, why don't I want to use single quotes for names of columns? I have learned SQL on the job and this is the only way my team of non-programmers do things. Could you share the reasoning so I can take it back to my team?

Comment: @vaughn42sv . . . Single quotes are the delimiter for string constants (and hence dates as well).  Using single quotes to delimit column names is confusing, because it might work (in some databases) for defining the column.  It *never* works for referring to the column.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the individual records of July are followed by a column indicating the `date` of each entry then you could try the following and given the `locale` you could format the `numeric` output.

```
SELECT FORMAT(100*SUM(Column A)/SUM(Column B), 'N', 'en-US') AS 'Success Ratio %'
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY MONTH(Entry Date)
```

OR simply

```
SELECT 100*SUM(Column A)/SUM(Column B) AS 'Success Ratio %'
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY MONTH(Entry Date)
```

OR even better

```
SELECT FORMAT(100*SUM(A)/SUM(B), 'N', 'en-US') AS 'Success Ratio %', DATENAME(MONTH,MAX(C)) AS 'MONTH'
FROM mytest
GROUP BY MONTH(C)
```

Try it out in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca04b/1).